# How do I create a lambda function via terraform with my source zip in a remote location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "Notifier" {

  filename          = "notifier.zip"
}
```

I would like to point to a `notifier.zip` file in github.com  , will I be able to do that ??

Comment: @DanielC Terraform is not wrapping CloudFormation, it is calling the AWS API directly. In this instance it would be calling the AWS `CreateFunction` or `UpdateFunctionCode` API endpoints.

Comment: @user2062360 is the zip in a public repository?